# Why does a specialized form of cong in Idris fail to typecheck?

Tags: types, proof, idris, dependent-type

Idris has the `cong` function which is pretty straightforward.

```
cong : {f : t -> u} -> a = b -> f a = f b
cong Refl = Refl
```

If I create a specialized form of `cong` to addition over zero it fails to typecheck.

```
cong0 : {f : Nat -> Nat} -> a + Z = a -> f (a + Z) = f a
cong0 Refl = Refl
```

In Idris 1 I get

```
When checking left hand side of cong0:
When checking an application of Main.cong0:
        Type mismatch between
                a = a (Type of Refl)
        and
                a + 0 = a (Expected type)
        
        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        a
                and
                        plus a 0
```

In Idris 2 I get

```
Can't solve constraint between:
        ?_ [no locals in scope]
and
        plus ?_ 0
at:
2       cong0 Refl = Refl
              ^^^^
```

However, if I just replace the definition of `cong0` with `cong` everything compiles just fine:

```
cong0 : {f : Nat -> Nat} -> a + Z = a -> f (a + Z) = f a
cong0 = cong
```

If I also just don't repeat `a` on both sides of equality everything seems to be fine.

```
cong0 : {f : Nat -> Nat} -> a + Z = b -> f (a + Z) = f b
cong0 Refl = Refl
```

What's going on? Why can I directly prove the generalized version of `cong0` but not its specialized version?

Is this something to do with the abstract variable `a` appearing on both sides of `=` with different syntactic forms? If so why does Idris disallow such a thing to unify with a `Refl` pattern, but is perfectly content to allow `a = b`?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to a subtlety in dependent type theory. The best way to think about pattern matching is as syntactic sugar for the application of "induction rules". For equality, the rule is

```
eq_ind : (a : Type) -> 
         (x : a) ->
         (P : (y : a) -> x = y -> Type) ->
         P x Refl ->
         (y : a) ->
         (q : x = y) ->
         P y q
eq_ind a x P reflCase x Refl = reflCase
```

All pattern matching on the type `x = y` must be reducible to an "obvious" application of `eq_ind`.

In this case, we see that we can write

```
cong : {f : t -> u} -> x = y -> f x = f y
cong {t} {u} {f} {x} {y} q = eq_ind t x (\y, _ => f x = f y) Refl y q
```

This is a pretty straightforward interpretation of the pattern matching in your definition of `cong` as a special case of applying `eq_ind`.

In fact, we can also write

```
cong1 : {f : Nat -> Nat} -> a + Z = b -> f (a + Z) = f b
cong1 {f} {a} {b} q = eq_ind Nat (a + Z) (\b, _ => f (a + Z) = f b) Refl b q
```

Note that we can only use `eq_ind` when we're trying to prove something of the form `(y : a) -> (q : x = y) -> P y q`. In other words, the right side of the equality type must be a variable `y` which does not occur free in `x`.

We cannot directly use `eq_ind` to prove the statement `{f : Nat -> Nat} -> a + Z = a -> f (a + Z) = f a` because in the expression `a + Z = a`, the variable on the right side also occurs in the left side. The types just don't work out. Because there isn't an obvious translation from your pattern matching to the use of `eq_ind`, Idris can't let you use pattern matching.

However, we can definitely use `cong` as a helper function in order to prove that `a + Z = a -> f (a + Z) = f a`. In fact, that is the best way to prove this statement.

Note that we also cannot "obviously" use `eq_ind` to prove the symmetric statement to `cond1`, which is `{f : t -> u} -> b = (a + Z) -> f b = f (a + Z)`. Thus, we also cannot use pattern matching here. Even though we can use pattern matching to prove `a + Z = b -> f (a + Z) = b`, we can't do it with the equal signs the other way around.

If you want more details on how this works, you should look into "path induction" and ideally read the first two chapters of the Homotopy Type Theory book.